# loop through database item, sum values and parse unwanted text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, parsing, loops, sum

I am wondering about for each loop. What I have is several columns for each item and I want to loop trough it and take out values from each column that has the name "inch".

Now to the part where the value is not just numbers but also letters, like "1 inch".

So I have 3 items that has "1 inch","5 inch" and "10 inch".

So I want to take the "inch" (parse I guess) out and add these three together so the sum is 16.

This if for windows phone local database c#

I have a ViewModel and a Model. The columns in the Model looks like this

```
    private string _itemSpring;

    [Column]
    public string ItemSpring
    {
        get { return _itemSpring; }
        set
        {
            if (_itemSpring != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("ItemSpring");
                _itemSpring = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemSpring");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i view it through my viewmodel with connection string to db,

```
// LINQ to SQL data context for the local database.
    public ToDoDataContext toDoDB;

    // Class constructor, create the data context object.
    public ToDoViewModel(string toDoDBConnectionString)
    {
        toDoDB = new ToDoDataContext(toDoDBConnectionString);
    }
```

Comment: you need to provide what you came up with so far, and also which language ?

Comment: If it's in the database as a string '1 inch' you're going to need to substring out the first part and then cast it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 3 items are like this,

```
string[] items = { "1 inch", "5 inch", "10 inch" };
int totalCount = 0;
foreach(var item in items)
{
   string[] substrings = item.split(' ');
   totalCount += int.Parse(substrings[0]);
}
string finalString = totalCount + " inch";
```

UPDATE:
I dont understand whether you are asking on how to retrieve the data from database or how to process the data that is fetched from DB.

Assuming the second case, check the following answer

Fetch the data from database and convert it into a List or an ObservableCollection
and then you can use the following query on that to get what you want.

```
foreach(var item in ItemsList)
totalCount += double.Parse(item.ItemSize.Split(' ')[0]);
```

or otherwise

```
foreach(var item in ItemsList)
totalCount += double.Parse(item.ItemSize.Replace(" inch", ""));
```

Comment: What if my items are different all the time.

Comment: How different? Show all the possibilities so that I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: i can be 1.5 inch, 2 inch 2.5 inch up to 10. Shouldnt the string[] items have the acctual database columns in there some how. like App.ViewModel.Items.InchColmn.

Comment: It is not fair to ask how to parse your DB data, without sharing any of your DB structure. How is your inch column defined in your db? how are you accessing it? what is the query you are using right now?

Comment: Anyone have some tips where I can read about some looping and summary of looped values.